# Unable to update view - The target table of the UPDATE is not updateable

Tags: mysql, sql, view, sql-update

I have a view (`v_licence_data`) that is constructed like so:

```
SELECT "licences"."user_id"             AS "user_id",
       "licences"."licence_id"          AS "licence_id",
       "licences"."licence_created"     AS "licence_created",
       "licences"."licence_expiry"      AS "licence_expiry",
       "licences"."licence_key"         AS "licence_key",
       "licences"."machine_id"          AS "machine_id",
       "users"."email"                  AS "email",
       "users"."first_name"             AS "first_name",
       "users"."last_name"              AS "last_name",
       "users"."date_created"           AS "date_created",
       "machines"."machine_fingerprint" AS "machine_fingerprint",
       "licences"."id"                  AS "id"
FROM   (("licences"
         LEFT JOIN "users"
                ON(( "licences"."user_id" = "users"."id" )))
        LEFT JOIN "machines"
               ON(( "licences"."machine_id" = "machines"."id" )))
```

I am trying to do an `UPDATE` on the view:

```
UPDATE v_licence_data
SET email = 'test'
WHERE licence_id = '6787C1-07B5F5-CDC649-28D156-A8706B-V3'
```

However I get the following error: `The target table v_licence_data of the UPDATE is not updatable`

I have read the [Updatable and Insertable Views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-updatability.html) documentation, and I believe that my view meets all the conditions to be an updateable view.

How can I resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: outer (left) join is the problem, it is mentioned in the link you posted.

Answer (score 0):

The [Updatable and Selectable Views documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-updatability.html) states that multi-table views can only be updated if they exclusively use `INNER JOINS`:

> It is sometimes possible for a multiple-table view to be updatable, assuming that it can be processed with the `MERGE` algorithm. For this to work, the view must use an `inner join` (not an `outer join` or a `UNION`). Also, only a single table in the view definition can be updated, so the `SET` clause must name only columns from one of the tables in the view.

So unless you're able to change your view, the only option you have is directly updating the table. This will allow you to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
   UPDATE licenses l
LEFT JOIN users u
       ON l.user_id = u.id
      SET u.email = 'test'
    WHERE l.license_id = '6787C1-07B5F5-CDC649-28D156-A8706B-V3'
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1f97d786adc1abadbc36abee9a4481cb).